# Как конкурентно выполнить команды в разных сервисах через ssh?

Tags: golang, ssh

Текущий код для проверки актуальности гита на сервере выглядит примерно таким образом:

```go
func CompareCommit(service []structures.ServiceControls) ([]structures.ServiceControls, error) {
    hosts := map[string]string{}
    for _, s := range service {
        if s.Controlgit {
            if _, ok := hosts[s.Hostssh]; !ok {
                hosts[s.Hostssh] = s.Userssh + ":" + s.Passwordssh
            }
        }
    }

    rw := &sync.RWMutex{}
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    for host, userPass := range hosts {
        c := NewCli()
        splitted := strings.Split(userPass, ":")

        if err := c.CreateSSHConnection(splitted[0], splitted[1], host); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        defer c.GetSSHClient().Close()

        for i, s := range service {
            if s.Hostssh == host {
                wg.Add(1)
                go func(c Cli, s *structures.ServiceControls, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
                    defer wg.Done()

                    commands := []string{
                        "cd " + s.Directory,
                        "git log -n 1 --pretty=format:\"%H\"",
                        "git ls-remote origin master",
                    }

                    c.SetCommand(strings.Join(commands, "; "))

                    hashes, err := c.ExecuteCommand()
                    if err != nil {
                        rw.Lock()
                        s.GitActual = err.Error()
                        rw.Unlock()
                        return
                    }

                    localHash := hashes[:40]
                    remoteHash := hashes[40:80]

                    if localHash == remoteHash {
                        rw.Lock()
                        s.GitActual = "true"
                        s.GitDate = time.Now()
                        rw.Unlock()
                    } else {
                        rw.Lock()
                        s.GitActual = "false"
                        rw.Unlock()
                    }
                }(c, &service[i], wg)
            }
        }
    }
    wg.Wait()

    return service, nil
}
```

в принципе данная функция возвращает большую часть значений корректно, но при создании новой сессии внутри ExecuteCommand, перед выполнением команд для некоторых сервисов, возвращается такая ошибка:

```
ssh: rejected: administratively prohibited (open failed)
```

ExecuteCommand выглядит вот так:

```go
func (c *cli) ExecuteCommand() (string, error) {
    c.rw.RLock()
    command := c.command
    client := c.client
    c.rw.RUnlock()

    if command == "" {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("команда для выполнения не установлена")
    }

    var b bytes.Buffer

    if client != nil {
        if err := c.NewSSHSession(); err != nil {
            return "", err
        }

        c.rw.RLock()
        session := c.session
        c.rw.RUnlock()

        defer session.Close()

        session.Stdout = &b

        if err := session.Run(command); err != nil {
            return "", fmt.Errorf("команда %s завершилась с ошибкой: %w", command, err)
        }

        return b.String(), nil
    }

    return "", fmt.Errorf("отсутствует подключение к ssh клиенту")
}
```

и мой вопрос заключается, во-первых, в том, что эта ошибка значит, а во-вторых, каким можно ее избежать?

Comment: что в значении `MaxSessions` в файле sshd_config ?

Comment: @senior-pomidor, эта строка закоменчена, раскоментил и выставил значение, спасибо!

Comment: помогло ведь, верно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

необходимо задать `MaxSessions` в файле `sshd_config`